# C# Tie Other Values to Enumerations

Tags: c#, .net, generics, attributes

I'm green on C# and .NET.  I'm trying to tie other values to enumerations.  I'm also trying to use a generic function to retrieve these values (from http://omegacoder.com/?p=28).  The generic function does not work for me.  It just returns the name of the Attribute type.  I defined a custom Attribute, but I don't know how to get at the "Num" Property of it.

Basically, if I have a CRC polynomial enumeration value of Crc32ieeeNormal (1), I want to be able to retrieve the polynomial itself.  These must be separate numbers, as the enumeration must be a single byte indicator.

I'm sure one could write separate structures, using the same numbers, etc., and that's what I'll do if I have to, but I'd like it all tied together.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace csAttributes
{
    using System.Reflection;        // to retrieve attribute values

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // I know this isn't right, but can't figure out how to get the attribute value....
            CrcPolynomialTypesEnum crc = CrcPolynomialTypesEnum.Crc32ieeeNormal;
            Console.WriteLine(Utility.ExtractAttribute<U64Attribute, CrcPolynomialTypesEnum>(crc));
            Console.WriteLine(crc.ExtractAttribute<U64Attribute, CrcPolynomialTypesEnum>());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public enum CrcPolynomialTypesEnum : byte
        {
            // These must be explicitly defined as they are values used as indicators in a file.
            [U64(0)]
            Crc32InvalidOrNotSet = 0x00,

            [U64(0x04C11DB7)]
            Crc32ieeeNormal = 0x01,

            [U64(0xEDB88320)]
            Crc32ieeeReversed = 0x02,

            [U64(0x1EDC6F41)]
            Crc32CastagnoliNormal = 0x0A,

            [U64(0x82F63B78)]
            Crc32CastagnoliReversed = 0x0B
        }

    }

    public static class Utility { 
        // from http://omegacoder.com/?p=28, 8/11/2017
        /// <summary>
        /// If an enum has a custom attrbute, this will returrn that attribute or null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TCustomAttr">The type of the <code class="backtick">custom attribute</code> to extract from the enum.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TEnumItance">The enum currently being viewed..</typeparam>
        /// <param name="instance">The instance.</param>
        /// <returns>The custom attribute (TCustomAttr) or null</returns>
        public static TCustomAttr ExtractAttribute<TCustomAttr, TEnum>(this TEnum instance)
        {
            if (instance != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    FieldInfo fieldInfo = instance.GetType()
                        .GetField(instance.ToString());

                    var attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TCustomAttr), false)
                        .ToList();

                    if (attributes.Any())
                        return (TCustomAttr)attributes[0];

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }

            return default(TCustomAttr);
        }

    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = true)]
    public class U64Attribute : Attribute
    {
        private UInt64 n;

        public U64Attribute(UInt64 num)
        {
            n = num;
        }

        public UInt64 Num
        {
            get
            {
                return n;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Edit: Thank you, Kevin.  Funny thing is, the "Num" property wasn't available earlier, but now it is.  Must have been something I didn't have right earlier.

Edit 2: Using a generic here may be pointless, and a more specific function to retrieve the value seems to be better for this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I read all the code right. What it looks like is that you are getting the class U64Attribute and trying to write it instead of the .Num...that should be an easy change, just use .Num appended to the ExtractAttribute call:

```
Console.WriteLine(Utility.ExtractAttribute<U64Attribute, CrcPolynomialTypesEnum>(crc).Num);
```